# Increment eax register by 4 bytes

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a below code

```
.section .data 
 myvar: .long 4,3,2,1

.section .text
.globl _start
 _start:
movl $0, %edi
movl $myvar+0, %eax 
movl $myvar+16, %ebx 
int $0x80
```

I want to keep incrementing eax and would like to compare the eax with ebx to check if i have reached the end of my array.

How do i increment my register with 4 bytes.

Comment: `addl $4, %eax`... Not clear what the `int $0x80` is for...

Comment: @FrankKotler int $0x80 is just to end the program, that can be ignore, Thanks for your comment, i will check with addl

Answer (score 2):

The thing you want is pretty simple, but you need to add few additional information to your code, because you're writing x86 assembly and not any high-level language like Java or C#.

First solution is to keep counting in `ecx` and compare it with array length.

```
...
arrlen: .long (arrlen - myvar)/4
...
xor %ecx, %ecx
loop:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl $myvar(, %ecx, 4), %eax
    pushl %ecx
    ...
    //fill other registers
    ...
    int $0x80

    popl %ecx
    incl %ecx
    cmpl %ecx, arrlen
    jne loop
```

Another way is just to check value loaded. After calling system call, you can't be sure that it won't affect register values (some system calls return information in same registers as used for parameters). You can simply save it on stack, or faster, do comparasion direcly in memory.

```
pushl $0x0
loop:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl (%esp), %ecx
    movl $myvar(, %ecx, 4), %eax
    ...
    //fill other registers
    ...
    int $0x80

    incl (%esp)
    cmpl $myvar(, %ecx, 4), 1
    jne loop
```

To save few bytes of memory (probably 4 for each instruction using it), you can move value of `$myvar` to some register (that shouldn't be used for syscall). Which one will it be is only up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I used addl instead of using stack,

```
.section .data
mydata:
 .long 1,2,3,4

.section .text
.globl _start
 _start:
 movl $0, %edi          # initialize edi to 0
 movl $mydata+0 , %edx      # we are storing address of first element in edx
 movl $mydata+16, %ecx      # we are storing the address of last element to ecx
 movl mydata(,%edi,4), %eax
 movl %eax, %ebx
  start_loop:
  cmpl %edx, %ecx       # we are checking if edx has moved to last element
  je loop_exit         # if starting and ending address are same we exit the loop
  addl $4, %edx     # We want to move by 4 bytes so we increment edx by 4 
  incl %edi             # We increment %edi by 1 
  movl mydata(,%edi,4), %eax    # Access the next data item
  cmpl %ebx, %eax       # compare the current item with existing largest value
  jle start_loop            # if the current item is less, we repeat

 movl %eax, %ebx            # if current item is highest, we interchange and update ebx
 jmp start_loop             # we repeat steps till we reach end of the loop

loop_exit:
movl $1, %eax           # call exit system call
int $0x80           # Call Bruce Wayne
```

The above worked.